# PostScript statusdict name lookup order

Tags: postscript

at Lvl 2,3 you have this on the dictstack:

```
systemdict | globaldict | userdict
```

at Lvl 1 you have the statusdict with product-depended operators.
From what I understand is statusdict a dictionary which can be accesses via the "statusdict"-key in "systemdict". (correct me if I'm wrong).

Normally if you do a name lookup it first looks in userdict, next in globaldict and last in systemdict.

Let's say I'm at languagelevel 2 or 3 where I have systemdict, globaldict and userdict. for compatibility I also have statusdict.
What is the order of name lookup if you have a statusdict? Does the interpreter check statusdict before systemdict or after systemdict? (or another point?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I recall (and its been a long time since I looked at level 1) the only way to use operators from statusdict was to emit a specific 'statusdict begin' to push the dictionary on the dict stack, or similar.

For example, Ghostscript's statusdict implements the old level 1 'setpage', if you try:

```
612 792 0 setpage
```

Then you will get an 'undefined' error. However this:

```
statusdict begin 612 792 0 setpage end
```

will work. I tried something similar on another level 3 interpreter with the same result.

So I'd say you don't need to worry about looking up statusdict, any code which wants to use its contents must first put it on the dictionary stack, use get or similar to access the dictionary.

Comment: and for a level 1 interpreter. Does this mean that you also have to use statusdict begin first?

Comment: As I recall, yes, but like I said, its been an awfully long time since I used a level 1 interpreter!

Comment: You have to use `begin` to use automatic name-lookup, but you could also do `612 792 statusdict /setpage get exec` or similar.  There are some things in statusdict used by old or long-lived drivers like TeX has. I've had to add a few things to run those.